# Phonegap Application Not Scrolling

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, android-webview

I have developed a Phonegap application, and am now trying to run it in the android emulator. My problem is that the application doesn't scroll in the emulator or device, but it works well in a normal browser like mozilla or chrome. Butwhen I test in the emulator or device then it doesn't scroll.

Here is my html file http://pastie.org/3981916

And here is my css file  http://pastie.org/3981918

I am not able to find a solution to this problem, can any one help me out please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you cant get the normal html scroll behavior when trying to create a app using phonegap on android.
you cant get the overflow:scroll effect for any of the html elements.
you'll need to make use of third party libraries such as  [jquerymobile,](http://jquerymobile.com/)   [iscroll4,](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) etcfor getting the native look and feel.
or also you can construct your own logic

Comment: hi! can u suggest me some example of using iscroll in phonegap application?

Comment: i'm using it for my app. visit here http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/ it is a simple example of using iscroll. but hey !! even iscoll4 has some issues so follow its google group and u'll need to modify source as mentioned in the group

Comment: thanks i run that example it's working well now i when i am implementing in my application,than it gets scroll but only half of the portion i can see why does it happens?

Comment: need to modify the css as according to your need if you want a full proof solution then go for jquery. there are demos on the site. if u want to use iscroll then there is some code needed to modify.